# How to double input of an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

So, I am trying to take an array input of `6,7,34,7,6` and create a method to have the ouput be `6 6 7 7 34 34 7 7 6 6`.

How would i go about that?

So far I have:

```
public int [] twice (int[] ary)

int [] A =  new int [ary.length * 2]

A [0] = 6;
A [1] = 7;
A [2] = 34;
A [3] = 7;
A [4] = 6;
```

But i don't know where to go from there.

Comment: you want output as 6 6 7 7.. or 6,7,34,7,6, 6,7,34,7,6.. because your current approach is going towards second result..

Comment: the output as 6 6 7 7...

Comment: @HelloBeans You might want to have a look at my answer as I corrected it (in previous version it threw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
public static int[] twice(int[] ary) {
    int[] A = new int[ary.length * 2];
    for(int i=0, j=0;j<ary.length;i=i+2,j++) {
        A[i] = A[i+1] = ary[j];
    }
    return A;
}
```

Comment: nice. j is also unnecessary.
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result[i*2] = result[i*2+1] = arr[i];
}

Answer (score 0):

Just use two for loops

```
{
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++) System.print(ary[i]);
for (int i=0;i<5;i++) System.print(ary[4-i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int [] twice (int[] ary)
    {
      int [] A =  new int [ary.length * 2];
      //take 2 variables one to point input array and 1 for output array
        int c = 0;
        for(int n: ary) {
         //put each element of input array twice in output array
          A[c] = A[c+1] = n;
          c += 2;
      }
      //return output array
      return A;
    }
```

Comment: @AniketSahrawat ary.length is itself a field which does not require any computation and hence no performance improvement. On the other hand if you are creating a new variable to store it then you are putting one more variable in java stack memory.

Answer (score 0):

As your input values look like they're sorted and then you put the same values to destination array again in descending order, you might want to try attempt with sorting your input first depending on what you want to achieve:

```
public int [] twice(int[] ary) {
    int[] temporary = new int[ary.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) { // copying ary to temporary
        temporary[i] = ary[i];
    }
    Arrays.sort(temporary); // sorting  temporary in ascending order
    int[] result = new int[ary.length * 2]; // creating double sized result array
    for(int i = 0; i < temporary.length; i++) { // copying sorted contents of temporary at the beginning of result array
        result[i] = temporary[i];
    }
    int j = 0 ;
    for(int i = result.length - 1; i >= result.length / 2; i--) { // inserting contents of temporary from the end of result array to the middle ("from right to left")
        result[i] = temporary[j++];
    }
    return result; // returning result array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to add the values at the end

// Java program explaining System class method - arraycopy()

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class NewClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int s[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100};
        int d[] = Arrays.copyOf(s, s.length*2);

        int source_arr[], sourcePos, dest_arr[], destPos, len;
        source_arr = s;
        sourcePos = 0;
        dest_arr = d;
        destPos = s.length;
        len = s.length;

        // Use of arraycopy() method
        System.arraycopy(source_arr, sourcePos, dest_arr, 
                                            destPos, len);
        // Print elements of destination after
        System.out.print("final dest_array : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
            System.out.print(d[i] + " ");
    }
}
```